# Crontab python django issue

Tags: python, django, cron

The following works as expected:

```
python /usr/share/str8RED/manage.py getLiveResults
```

However, nothing happens when I use the following cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * python /usr/share/str8RED/manage.py getLiveResults
```

Using the link below I have managed to create a error log:

http://matthewwittering.com/blog/django-tips/running-a-django-management-commands-with-crontab.html

This informs me that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/str8RED/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I can get cronjab working and running every minute with echo "Hello World".  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Contents of getLiveResults.py:

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from straightred.models import StraightredTeam
from straightred.xmlsoccer import XmlSoccer


#The class must be named Command, and subclass BaseCommand
class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "My test command"

    # A command must define handle()
    def handle(self, *args, **options):


        xmlsoccer = XmlSoccer(api_key='XYZ', use_demo=False)
        teams = xmlsoccer.call_api(method='GetAllTeamsByLeagueAndSeason',
                                   seasonDateString='1617',
                                   league='English League Championship')

        numberOfTeamsUpdated = 0

        for team in teams:

            if '{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}Team_Id' in team.keys():
                teamUpdate = StraightredTeam(teamid=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}Team_Id'],
                                             teamname=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}Name'],
                                             country=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}Country'],
                                             stadium=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}Stadium'],
                                             homepageurl=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}HomePageURL'],
                                             wikilink=team['{http://xmlsoccer.com/Team}WIKILink'],
                                             currentteam=1)
                teamUpdate.save()
                numberOfTeamsUpdated = numberOfTeamsUpdated + 1


        self.stdout.write("Hello world!")
```

Comment: What `getliveResults` does?

Comment: If you are using virtual env, then you need to activate the environment,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using virtual env, then you need to activate the environment,

maybe something like:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/share/str8RED/.env/bin/python /usr/share/str8RED/manage.py getLiveResults
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/str8RED/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management